# How does SanDisk name drives in eject dialog

Tags: usb-flash-drive, rename, eject

I have a Sandisk Cruzer Blade flash drive and its been driving me insane trying to figure out how they make it say Eject Cruzer Blade instead of Eject Removable Disc.

Comment: It's the name they gave to the partition when formating. You can do the same with any flash drive.

Comment: @MichaelBay why don't you post that as an answer?

Comment: @music2myear  A little short but OK, done.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a Sandisk Cruzer Blade flash drive and (...) trying to figure out how they make it say Eject Cruzer Blade instead of Eject Removable Disc.

Any partition can be given a name (label) when created/formated.

*Sandisk Cruzer Blade* is the name chosen by the manufacturer when formating the partition. You can do the same with any flash drive.

Comment: I was talking about the thing that is above the partition name(s). like it says remove Cruzer blade then below that is the partition names. i want to know how they change that name